# How to I find out that I compile for iOS

Tags: android, ios, c

I have some C code which is compiled for iOS, Android and MS-Windows which need to include `malloc.h`. Now my Problem is that on iOS the include is `malloc/malloc.h`.

So I need something like this:

```
#if defined (…)
#   include   <malloc/malloc.h>
#else
#   include   <malloc.h>
#endif
```

What to put in at the place of … ?

PS: Yes, I did google it but I just did not get the keywords right. A LMGTFY would be find so I know what I should have googled.

Comment: You can try `#if defined(IOS) || defined(OSX)`

Comment: Add anything you want and supply the value for the macro in your makefile.

Answer (score 1):

You could use following define

```
#if defined(__APPLE__)
#   include   <malloc/malloc.h>
#else
#   include   <malloc.h>
#endif
```